# Webapp2 redirect 404 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, webapp2

I'm having troubles with redirect function. When I call it with `self.redirect("/index.html")` the server goes to `http://localhost:10080/index.html` and alert 404 page not found.

Log:

`HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-04-12 12:32:39,029 module.py:737] default: "POST /subscribe HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-04-12 12:32:39,046 module.py:737] default: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 154
INFO     2015-04-12 12:32:39,223 module.py:737] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2015-04-12 12:32:39,296 module.py:737] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -`

Comment: That means you do not have /index.html in the routing, or the routing configuration is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Redirect takes a URL. You probably want to `self.redirect("/")` but without knowing your URL mappings, that's just a guess.